# Mongodb-express wont compose with docker-compose.yaml

Tags: mongodb, docker

whenever i try to compose mongodb and mongodb-express i get the below error

```
C:\Users\ayan9\Documents\repository\ayanpal_dot_me [master +2 ~0 -0 !]> docker compose up
[+] Running 3/3
 - Network ayanpal_dot_me_default            Created                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 - Container ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  Created                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 - Container ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        Created                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
Attaching to ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1, ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.254+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.255+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.257+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.257+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.258+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"5924e60df736"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.8","gitVersion":"c87e1c23421bf79614baf500fda6622bd90f674e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.259+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.261+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.261+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=15474M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.681+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652017564:681852][1:0x7ff209735c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.681+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652017564:681919][1:0x7ff209735c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.690+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":429}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.690+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.704+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.704+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.714+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.714+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"1b6aefca-c53e-42d0-9c9b-d2e8eee30340"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"1b6aefca-c53e-42d0-9c9b-d2e8eee30340"}}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.728+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.version","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":20459,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting featureCompatibilityVersion","attr":{"newVersion":"5.0"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"b0eb7b0e-af74-4183-8a67-ecd9e7de29cc"}},"options":{"capped":true,"size":10485760}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.743+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"local.startup_log","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.744+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"12df9af9-6392-49ea-abe2-84b860973329"}},"options":{}}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-05-08T13:46:04.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","commitTimestamp":null}}
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | Welcome to mongo-express
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | ------------------------
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://mongo:27017"
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | }]
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ayanpal_dot_me-mongo-express-1 exited with code 0
```

My docker-compose.yaml is as below

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_PASSOWRD=rootpass
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
```

Just trying to run mongodb and mongodb express via docker
I have tried adding the ports to both the server configs of mongodb and mongodb-express
also added the volumes and networks but this error is very confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues. The first is that Express tries to connect to the database using a default hostname of 'mongo'. Yours is called 'mongodb' so it can't find it. The easiest way to fix this is by naming the service `mongo` rather than `mongodb`.

Now mongo-express can find the mongo container, but now the second issue arises: The mongo-express container tries to connect to the mongo database immediately after startup, but the mongo database isn't ready to accept connections at that time. An easy way around that is to set the restart option to always, so the container restarts until it succeeds.

Try this

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_PASSOWRD=rootpass
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Comment: one more thing, is the 'version' tag necessary?

Comment: No, 'version' isn't necessary. If you don't have it, compose will interpret the file using the latest spec. I like using it, so people can see what version of the spec the file was written for, in case something changes in the future.